# What is the relation between symbol duration and subcarrier frequency spacing in OFDM?

Tags: frequency, wifi, symbol, ofdm

What is the exact relation between symbol duration and frequency spacing?

You may know in WiFi6, about 11ax band, there are more sub-carriers compared to WiFi5 because of using shorter frequency spacing, but also uses a longer symbol duration. I guess there is some relation between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subcarrier spacing is equal to the reciprocal of the symbol time.

Equalizing narrower channels flattens group delay error and improves noise margin at the expense of added DSP processing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. you mean that added DSP processing needs more time to process, and it extends the symbol time?

Comment: It does everything

Comment: What do you mean everything?

Comment: More processing does not cause extended symbol time, it is caused by narrower BW

Comment: Thank you! my point is how are those two parameters reciprocal?

Comment: BW /symbol rate must be maintained by definition of deviation ratio and SNR improvement.